# How to properly align 2 text boxes side by side with css flexbox and cap the width for desktop view only?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 text boxes in a css flexbox. Left side is a tagline and right side is a brief summary. I am trying to have them display on a webpage side by side in the center of the page for desktops only (i.e. min width 1024px) but let these boxes stack up below that breakpoint (i.e. on tablets, phones with widths below 1024px). The challenge here is that both of these text boxes combined cannot exceed 50% of the width of the page (horizontally). Right now, when expanding screen size, the text stretches to the ends of the screen. I tried many different fixes and nothing I tried worked properly!

My HTML Code:

```
        <div class="info-block">
            <div class="info-item">
                <div class="info-col">
                    <h4>Modern Approach, Innovative Solutions, Accessible Support</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="info-col">
                    <div class="info-text">We approach problems with holistic and practical solutions, each and every time.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My CSS code:

```
.info-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0; 
}
.info-item:last-child {margin: 0;}
.info-col {
    width: 46.6%;
    font-size: 24px; 
}
.info-col:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}
.info-text {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    font-size: 24px; 
    line-height: 115%; 
    font-weight: 200; 
}


@media screen and (min-width: 1900px) {
    .info-text {
        margin-right: 200px;
        max-width: 420px; 
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
  .info-col {
      max-width: 420px; 
  }
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly, greatly appreciated!

[image: The layout I am trying to accomplish]

[image: mobile view]

Comment: You must use media queries for this purpose.

Comment: I have media queries set for this purpose but its not working right. The text still stretches to the sides of the screen rather than staying in the center. Please see added code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. Add this to your CSS:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* If screen size is maximum 1024px */
    .info-item {
        flex-direction: column; /* Set the flex direction to */
    }

    .info-col {
        width: 100%; /* Setting width to 100% */
    }
}
```

To keep the items centered, you need to set the width to 100% while you stack the columns on smaller screens.

Comment: Thank you, but it's still not working properly. The text boxes still stretch to the sides of the screen on a laptop with screen width of 1920px. I am trying to cap the width of each textbox on laptops/desktops with width greater than 1024px (i.e. both text boxes should not exceed 50% of page width and should remain in the center).

Comment: I just added a picture to illustrate the layout I am hoping to accomplish (the 2 text boxes are the orange boxes in the image). Thank you.

Comment: Hmm I do have an idea. Keep the width: 100% in the media query. Then add `padding: 0 25%` to `.info-item`. You may change that `25%` to some horizontal padding you want.

Comment: Thank you. This worked well on desktop view, but mobile stacking is awkward (adding screenshot above). Is there a way to let the text box stack up on mobile and then let the text flow naturally at that point?

Comment: Thank you @Solved Games. Adjusting padding on info-item according to different breakpoints helped fixed this. Thank you so much!